# ACL Laravel usando ADMINLTE

Tags: laravel-5, acl, adminlte

Bom dia.

Estou usando laravel 5.5 e adminlte. Implementei o acl com middlewares e uso o can para testar as permissões.
Eu gostaria de coloca o can('centrocusto') no menu do adminLte. Não está funcionando. Alguém já fez isto? Sabe como se faz?
Exemplo:
                @can
                [
                    'text' => 'Centro de Custo',
                    'icon' => 'file',
                    'url'  => 'admin/centrocusto',
                ],
                @endcan
Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

O AdminLTE possui a opção `can` se quiser mostrar condicionalmente o item de menu, ela se integra com a funcionalidade Gate do Laravel, e é definida diretamente no array, dessa forma:

```
[ 
    'text' => 'Centro de Custo', 
    'icon' => 'file', 
    'url' => 'admin/centrocusto', 
    'can' => 'centrocusto'
]
```

[Referência](https://github.com/jeroennoten/Laravel-AdminLTE#51-menu)